# Python 3.2: Battle.net scraper gives 404 on certain URLs

Tags: python, screen-scraping, http-status-code-404, web-scraping

I'm writing a battle.net screen scraper in python, and I want to scrape [this page](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/).

Problem is, I get a 404 when I try to download it using my script.
However, viewing it in a web browser works just fine.

Here is the code I'm using if it helps ([requests](http://python-requests.org/) needed):

```py
def download(url, max_retries=10):
    for i in range(max_retries):
        print('Downloading: ' + url)
        r = requests.get(url)

        print('Status code: ' + str(r.status_code))

        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok: return r.content
    return None

download('http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit')
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Apparently the ending slash is necessary.

```
def download(url, max_retries=10):
    for i in range(max_retries):
        print('Downloading: ' + url)
        r = requests.get(url)

        print('Status code: ' + str(r.status_code))

        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok: return r.content
    return None

download('http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/')
```